# calling a function: unreported IOException must be declared to be thrown

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this code but there is an error to this,
I am not good with java so I posted my problem in here... this is my code

```
public static void SaveFile() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Saving File!");
        FileWriter toTextFile = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        for(x=0;x<new_num_book;x++){
                toTextFile.write(name[x]);
            }
        toTextFile.close();

    }

blah blah
else if(option == 5){
           SaveFile();
       }
```

the problem is that netbeans declares an error in accessing the SaveFile function. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're not catching the `IOException` the `SaveFile` method declares. But we would need to check more code to be sure about this.

Answer (score 2):

`saveFile` throws an `IOException`, you need to handle it or pass it on to the caller.

Take a look at [The `try` Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) for more details

Without more context it's hard to say what you should do.  You could handle the exception within the current method...

```
else if(option == 5){
    try {
        SaveFile();
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        // Handle the exception, tell the user, roll back, what ever
        // At the very least use exp.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

or declare the current method as throwing an `IOException` like the `SaveFile` method does

Your `SaveFile` method is also, potentially, leaving the file open...

If the file writing process fails for some reason, `toTextFile.close` may never be called, instead, you should take advantage of the `try-finally` block, for example

```
public static void SaveFile() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Saving File!");
    FileWriter toTextFile = null;
    try {
        toTextFile = new FileWriter("output.txt");
        for(x=0;x<new_num_book;x++){
            toTextFile.write(name[x]);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            toTextFile.close();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }
    }
}
```

or if you're using Java 7+, you can make use of the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) functionality, for example...

```
public static void SaveFile() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Saving File!");
    try (FileWriter toTextFile = new FileWriter("output.txt")) {
        for(x=0;x<new_num_book;x++){
            toTextFile.write(name[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to have a read of [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) and [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), which will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: @chano Basically, the `SaveFile` method has said that it can throw a `IOException`, it's washed its hands of been responsible for, the responsibility for handling the exception now belongs to the caller, it either needs to handle the exception or re-throw it to its caller...

Comment: it worked when i used this:
else if(option == 5){
           try {
               SaveFile();
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(FileHandling.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       }